# problema de estrutura de dados

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

Olá, estou fazendo um programa simples de estrutura de dados ele, tem que organizar alguns voos como por exemplo cadastrar aeroportos e voos desses aeroportes, cada linha de voo só pode ter um avião indo e um voltando, então eu fiz esse programa:

## main.c

```
#include <locale.h>
#include "menu.h"

//Programa principal
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Portuguese");

    _Aeroporto* cabAeroporto;
    aloca_memoria_aeroporto(&cabAeroporto);

    int op;

    menu(op);

    return 0;
}
```

## menu.h

```
#include "menu.c"

void Display_Menu();
int menu (int);
```

## menu.c

```
#include "src\src.h"

//2 Constantes para controle do fluxo do programa, um para congelar a tela e outro para limpar
#define CLEAR "cls"
#define PAUSE "pause"

//Display do menu do sistema de controle aereo
void Display_Menu()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("            Menu            \n");
    printf("1- Cadastrar Aeroporto.\n");
    printf("2- Lista Aeroportos.\n");
    printf("3- Remove Aeroporto.\n");
    printf("4- Cadastrar Voo.\n");
    printf("5- Ver Voos do aeroporto.\n");
    printf("6- Ver Voos da companhia.\n");
    printf("7- Remove voo.\n");
    printf("8- Experimentar a viagem iterativa.\n");
    printf("0- Sair\n\n");
    printf("Escolha uma opcao:");

}

int menu (int op)
{

    do{
        system(CLEAR);

        Display_Menu();

        scanf("%d",&op);

        switch (op){
            case 1:{
/*linha 38*/    cadastra_aeroporto(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                lista_aeroportos(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                remove_aeroportos(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
            case 4:{
                cadastra_voo(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
            case 5:{
                lista_voos_aeroporto(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
            case 6:{
                lista_voos_companhia(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
            case 7:{
                remove_voo(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
            case 8:{
                viagem_iterativa(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
        }

        system(PAUSE);

    }while(op != 0);
}
```

## src.h

```
#include "src.c"

void aloca_memoria_aeroporto();
void aloca_memoria_voo();
void cadastra_aeroporto();
void ler_dados_aeroporto();
void lista_aeroportos();
void imprime_aeroporto();
void remove_aeroportos();
void cadastra_voo();
void ler_dados_voo();
void lista_voos_aeroporto();
void imprime_voo();
void lista_voos_companhia();
void remove_voo();
void viagem_iterativa();
```

## src.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

//2 Constantes para controle do fluxo do programa, um para congelar a tela e outro para limpar
#define CLEAR "cls"
#define PAUSE "pause"

//Estrutura tipo voo
typedef struct _voo{
    char companhia [50];
    int numero;
    struct _aeroporto* destino;
    struct _voo* proximo;
    struct _voo* anterior;

} _Voo;

//Estrutura tipo aeroporto
typedef struct _aeroporto{
    char nome [50];
    struct _voo* voos;
    struct _aeroporto* proximo;
    struct _aeroporto* anterior;

} _Aeroporto;

//Busca na lista de aeroportos algum aeroporto cujo nome seja igual ao recebido
_Aeroporto* busca_aeroporto(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto, char nome_aeroporto[]){

    _Aeroporto* cursor;

    for(cursor = cabAeroporto->proximo ; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->proximo){
        if(strcmp(nome_aeroporto, cursor->nome) == 0){
            return cursor;
        }
  }
    return NULL;
}

//Recebe o nome do aeroporto de origem e de destino e verifica se existe algum voo parecido.
_Voo* busca_voo(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto, char origem[], char destino[]){

    _Voo* voos;
    _Voo* voo_cursor;
    _Aeroporto* aeroporto;

    aeroporto = busca_aeroporto(cabAeroporto, origem);

    if(aeroporto){
        voos = aeroporto->voos;

        for(voo_cursor = voos->proximo ; voo_cursor != NULL; voo_cursor = voo_cursor->proximo){
            if(strcmp(destino, (voo_cursor->destino)->nome) == 0){
                return voo_cursor;
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

//Aloca memoria para um tipo _Aeroporto
void aloca_memoria_aeroporto(_Aeroporto** aeroporto){
    (*aeroporto) = (_Aeroporto*) malloc (sizeof(_Aeroporto));

    if ((*aeroporto) == NULL){
        printf("Falha na alocacao da memoria\n");
    }

    (*aeroporto)->proximo = NULL;
}

//Aloca memoria para um tipo _Voo
void aloca_memoria_voo(_Voo** voo){
    (*voo) = (_Voo*) malloc (sizeof(_Voo));

    if ((*voo) == NULL){
        printf("Falha na alocacao da memoria\n");
    }

    (*voo)->proximo = NULL;
}

//Cadastra aeroporto
void cadastra_aeroporto(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){
    _Aeroporto* aeroporto;
    _Aeroporto* cursor;

    // Obtem o endereco do cabeca
    cursor = cabAeroporto;

    // Aloca a memoria para um novo elemento
    aloca_memoria_aeroporto(&aeroporto);
    aloca_memoria_voo(&aeroporto->voos);

    // Le o dados a serem cadastrados
    ler_dados_aeroporto(aeroporto);

    if(busca_aeroporto(cabAeroporto, aeroporto->nome)){
        printf("Nome de aeroporto jï¿½ registrado!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Navega ate o fim da lista
    while (cursor->proximo != NULL){
        cursor = cursor->proximo;
    }

    // Insere o novo elemento no fim da lista
    cursor->proximo = aeroporto;
    aeroporto->anterior = cursor;
}

//Faz a leitura de dados do aeroporto
void ler_dados_aeroporto(_Aeroporto* aeroporto){
    printf("Nome do aeroporto: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", aeroporto->nome);
}

// Varre a lista de aeroportos e imprime-os
void lista_aeroportos(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){

    _Aeroporto* cursor;

    printf("Aeroportos da lista\n\n");

    for(cursor = cabAeroporto->proximo ; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->proximo){
        imprime_aeroporto(cursor);
    }
}

//Imprime os dados de um aeroporto
void imprime_aeroporto(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){
    printf("Nome do aeroporto: %s\n",cabAeroporto->nome);
}

//Remove um aeroporto da lista de aeroportos
void remove_aeroportos(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){

    _Aeroporto* aeroporto;
    char nome_aux[50];
    int comp = 0;

    printf("Nome do aeroporto para ser removido: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_aux);

    aeroporto = busca_aeroporto(cabAeroporto, nome_aux);

    if(aeroporto){
        (aeroporto->anterior)->proximo = aeroporto->proximo;
         printf("Aeroporto remotivo com sucesso!\n\n");
    }else{
        printf("Nenhum aeroporto com este nome foi encontrado!\n\n");
    }
}

//Cadastra voo
void cadastra_voo(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){

    _Voo* voo;
    _Voo* cursor_voo;
    _Aeroporto* origem;
    _Aeroporto* destino;
    char nome_origem[50];
    char nome_destino[50];

    // Aloca a memoria para um novo elemento
    aloca_memoria_voo(&voo);

    // Le o dados a serem cadastrados
    ler_dados_voo(voo);

    printf("Nome da origem: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_origem);

    origem = busca_aeroporto(cabAeroporto, nome_origem);

    if(origem){
        cursor_voo = origem->voos;
    }else{
        printf("Nenhum aeroporto com este nome foi encontrado!\n\n");
    }

    printf("Nome do destino: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_destino);

    if(busca_voo(cabAeroporto, nome_origem ,nome_destino)){
        printf("Voo jï¿½ programado!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    destino = busca_aeroporto(cabAeroporto, nome_destino);

    if(destino){
        voo->destino = destino;
    }else{
        printf("Nenhum aeroporto com este nome foi encontrado!\n\n");
    }

    while (cursor_voo->proximo != NULL){
        cursor_voo = cursor_voo->proximo;
    }

    // Insere o novo elemento no fim da lista
    cursor_voo->proximo = voo;
    voo->anterior = cursor_voo;

    printf("Voo adicionado com sucesso!\n\n");
}

//Coleta os dadados do voo vindos do usuï¿½rio
void ler_dados_voo(_Voo* voo){
    printf("Nï¿½mero do voo: ");
    scanf("%d", &voo->numero);

    printf("Nome da companhia aï¿½rea: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", voo->companhia);
}

//Lista todos os voos que saem de um determinado aeroporto
void lista_voos_aeroporto(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){

    _Aeroporto* aeroporto;
    _Voo* voos;
    _Voo* voo_cursor;
    char nome_aux[50];

    printf("Nome do aeroporto: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_aux);

    aeroporto = busca_aeroporto(cabAeroporto, nome_aux);

    if(aeroporto){

        voos = aeroporto->voos;

        for(voo_cursor = voos->proximo ; voo_cursor != NULL; voo_cursor = voo_cursor->proximo){
            imprime_voo(voo_cursor);
        }

    }else{
        printf("Aeroporto nï¿½o encontrado!\n");
    }
}

//Imprime na tela os dados de um voo
void imprime_voo(_Voo* voo){
    printf("Nï¿½mero do voo: %d\n",voo->numero);
    printf("Nome da companhia: %s\n",voo->companhia);
    printf("Aeroporto de destino: %s\n",(voo->destino)->nome);
}

//Lista todos os voos que saem de um determinado companhia aerea
void lista_voos_companhia(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){

    _Aeroporto* aeroporto;
    _Voo* voos;
    _Voo* voo_cursor;
    char nome_aux[50];

    aeroporto = cabAeroporto;

    printf("Nome da companhia: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_aux);

    while (aeroporto->proximo != NULL){

        aeroporto = aeroporto->proximo;
        voo_cursor = aeroporto->voos;

        while (voo_cursor->proximo != NULL){
            voo_cursor = voo_cursor->proximo;

            if(strcmp(nome_aux, voo_cursor->companhia) == 0){
                printf("De %s para %s:\n",aeroporto->nome, (voo_cursor->destino)->nome);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Remove voo de uma lista de voos
void remove_voo(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){

    _Aeroporto* aeroporto;
    _Voo* voos;
    _Voo* voo_cursor;
    char nome_origem[50];
    char nome_destino[50];

    aeroporto = cabAeroporto;

    printf("Nome do aeroporto de origem: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_origem);

    aeroporto = busca_aeroporto(cabAeroporto, nome_origem);

    if(aeroporto){

        printf("Nome do aeroporto de destino: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_destino);

        voo_cursor = aeroporto->voos;

        while (voo_cursor->proximo != NULL){
            voo_cursor = voo_cursor->proximo;

            if(strcmp(nome_destino, (voo_cursor->destino)->nome) == 0){
                (voo_cursor->anterior)->proximo = voo_cursor->proximo;
                printf("Aeroporto remotivo com sucesso!\n\n");
            }
        }
    }else{
        printf("Aeroporto nï¿½o encontrado!\n");
    }
}

//Faz uma viagem iterativa com o usuï¿½rio
void viagem_iterativa(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){

    _Aeroporto* aeroporto;
    _Voo* voo_inicial = NULL;
    _Voo* voo_cursor = NULL;
    int op, aux;

    aeroporto = cabAeroporto;

    if(aeroporto->proximo == NULL){
        printf("Nï¿½o existe aeroportos cadastrados!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (aeroporto->proximo != NULL){

        aeroporto = aeroporto->proximo;

        if((aeroporto->voos)->proximo != NULL){
            voo_inicial = aeroporto->voos;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(voo_inicial == NULL){
        printf("Nenhum voo cadastrado!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    do{
        voo_cursor = voo_inicial;
        aux = 0;
        system(CLEAR);

        printf("            Voos do aeroporto %s!            \n", aeroporto->nome);

        while (voo_cursor->proximo != NULL){
            voo_cursor = voo_cursor->proximo;
            imprime_voo(voo_cursor);
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("\n0- Sair\n\n");
        printf("Escolha um voo:");

        scanf("%d",&op);

        voo_cursor = voo_inicial;

        if(op != 0){
            while (voo_cursor->proximo != NULL){
                voo_cursor = voo_cursor->proximo;
                if(voo_cursor->numero == op){
                    voo_inicial = (voo_cursor->destino)->voos;
                    aeroporto = voo_cursor->destino;
                    aux++;
                }
            }

            if(aux == 0){
                printf("Nï¿½mero de voo incorreto!\n");
                system(PAUSE);
            }
        }

    }while(op != 0);

}
```

Na `linha 38` do `menu.c` (esta marcado no código), estou tendo um erro que não estou conseguindo resolver, ele diz que `cabAeroporto` não está declarado, porem, ele esta declarado em `_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto;` em #main.c

Comment: Nao facas includes de ficheiros com extensao .c. Compila-os separadamente e deixa o linker fazer o que ele sabe.

Comment: @pmg como assim?

Comment: Qual é o teu Sistema Operativo e compilador?

Comment: uso Windows meu IDE no caso é o Falcon C++ o compilador é gcc gnu

Comment: com o gcc, depois de removeres os `#include` com ficheiros de extensao .c e reveres a estrutura de includes, faz `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic -Wall src.c menu.c main.c`. Isto vai compilar os 3 ficheiros de código e automaticamente "linkar" tudo num executavel.

Comment: essa é a ideia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## main.c

```
#include <locale.h>
#include "menu.h"

//Programa principal
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Portuguese");       // 1

    _Aeroporto* cabAeroporto;                // 2
    aloca_memoria_aeroporto(&cabAeroporto);  // 3

    int op;
    menu(op);                                // 4

    return 0;
}
```

No que respeita a `#include`s deves pensar assim:

// 1 o prototipo da funcao `setlocale()` e a definicao de `LC_CTYPE` estao no header `<locale.h>`. OK, ja incluido

// 2 O tipo de dados `_Aeroporto` esta definido no ficheiro `"src.c"`. Esta no ficheiro errado! Devo passar a definicao para um ficheiro com extensao .h e incluir esse ficheiro

// 3 o prototipo da funcao `aloca_memoria_aeroporto()` esta no ficheiro `"src.h"`. Portanto preciso de incluir este ficheiro. *Ja agora, este ficheiro parece um bom sitio para meter a definicao do tipo `_Aeroporto`*

// 4 o prototipo da funcao `menu()` esta no ficheiro `"menu.h"`. OK, ja incluido.

Comment: Fiz o que você falou e agora diz que esta dando `redefinition of struct_voo` e `conflicting types _Voo` (na linha 11 e 18 do src.c), tentei redefinir o nome da struct (em todos os lugares que usavase ela) e nao deu depois tentei mudar a variavel typo para outro nome tambem nao deu. nao sei o que esta faltando, lista encadeada esta dando um nó na minha cabeça

Comment: Os ficheiros .h devem conter prototipos de funcoes, definicoes de constantes (`#define`), definicoes de tipos (`typedef`) e pouco mais. Os ficheiros .c devem conter codigo e os `#includes` necessarios e pouco mais.

Comment: então eu fiz varias modificações no programa como eu posso mostralas para você sem modificar o post????

Comment: Hmm ... para manter as respostas coerentes, talvez fosse melhor fazeres outra pergunta.

Comment: sim é o que vou fazer, também já vou fechar aqui

Answer (score 1):

O `cabAeroporto` definido em main.c é uma variável local, que pertence apenas à função `main()`.
A função `menu()` definida em `menu.c` não conhece as variáveis locais de outras funções.

Para passares valores entre funções, usa os argumentos.

```
menu(op, cabAeroporto); // também passa o valor de cabAeroporto para a função
```

É claro que tens que alterar a função

```
int menu(int op, struct _aeroporto *cabAeroporto) { /* ... */ }
```

---

Se passar o valor não for suficiente, se precisas de alterar esse valor dentro da função inicial, tens de passar o endereço da variável

```
menu(op, &cabAeroporto); // também passa o endereço de cabAeroporto para a função
```

E a função passa a ser

```
int menu(int op, struct _aeroporto **cabAeroporto) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

As variáveis definidas dentro de um bloco de código (entre `{` e `}`) só podem ser acessadas dentro desse bloco (e dos blocos aninhados). Se você não quiser redefinir as funções, pode declarar a variável `cabAeroporto` como global, fora da função `main()`, como a seguir:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include "menu.h"

// Variável global - pode ser acessada em qualquer escopo do arquivo
_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto;

//Programa principal
int main()
{
  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Portuguese");

  aloca_memoria_aeroporto(&cabAeroporto);

  int op;

  menu(op);

  return 0;
}
```

Se precisar acessar essa mesma variável em outro arquivo, você deve declarar uma variável global de mesmo nome e precedida pela palavra-chave `extern` em cada arquivo que utilizar essa variável (`extern _Aeroporto* cabAeroporto;`).

Comment: Variáveis globais são más.

Comment: Bom, isso depende. Seria melhor utilizar uma linguagem orientada a objetos e declarar como um atributo estático para manter o encapsulamento.

Comment: compriendo que seria melhor com uma linguagem orientada a objeto, porem estou fazendo para estudar linguagem C.

Comment: porem, o meu erro é bem básico, muito obrigado por me ajudar =) @FilipeBeck

Comment: Então eu estava reparando e notei outra coisa @pmg e @FilipeBeck, o `_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto; [\n]
 aloca_memoria_aeroporto(&cabAeroporto);` que estavam decladados no `main.c` eles deveriam estar no `menu.c` dentro da função `int menu()`, pois o `main.c` não pega a biblioteca `src.h` é o `menu.c`  que faz isso, o que me traz outra duvida, eu deveria por um include do `src` no `main.c` tambem?

Comment: Você pode deixar a declaração global em `main.c` (`_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto;`) e redeclarar a mesma variável como extern em outros arquivos que precisam acessa-la (`extern _Aeroporto* cabAeroporto;`). Desse modo, você não estará criando uma nova variável global de mesmo nome, e sim dizendo ao compilador que existe uma variável global com esse nome que está definida em outro arquivo. Mas, como @pmg mesmo disse, você não deve fazer `#include` de arquivos de implementação (`.m`). Você deve compilar separadamente e depois linkar estes arquivos.